# How to increase the max http request size limit for HTTP triggers in Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, http, google-cloud-functions, http-status-code-413

I'm trying to invoke a google cloud function sending images larger than 50Mb. The purpose of the cloud function is to resize the images and upload them to google cloud storage.

However, when I send the HTTP post to my cloud function I get the following error: 413 Request Entity Too Large

Does anyone have any workaround to this error? Can I increase the http request size limit?

Answer (score 10):

The limit for HTTP trigger upload and download payload size is [documented at 10MB](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#resource_limits).  There is no way to get this limit increased, but you can always [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) explaining why it should be increased.

Comment: Hey Doug, What about compressing the data? are there any case studies on this or examples of compressing data for http responses from CF or http requests from clients? I was considering going the compression route but decided to just put the data inside of GCS then access through Firebase from the client (fit my use case pretty well).

Answer (score 2):

You can let the client upload directly to storage. authinticated onto his own user folder and security rules limiting the file size to whatever size you wish into a temp folder.

Then have a cloud function trigger started resizing the image.
And Delete the original image when finished.

I'm attaching a code example of mine -
you should add the a delete of the file after conversion...

```js
/**
 * When an image is uploaded in the Storage bucket We generate a thumbnail automatically using
 * ImageMagick.
 * After the thumbnail has been generated and uploaded to Cloud Storage,
 * we write the public URL to the Firebase Realtime Database.
 */
exports.generateThumbnail = functions.storage.object().onFinalize((object) => {
  console.log('Generated Started');

  // File and directory paths.
  const filePath = object.name;
  const contentType = object.contentType; // This is the image MIME type
  const fileDir = path.dirname(filePath);
  const fileName = path.basename(filePath);
  const thumbFilePath = path.normalize(path.join(fileDir, `${THUMB_PREFIX}${fileName}`));
  const tempLocalFile = path.join(os.tmpdir(), filePath);
  const tempLocalDir = path.dirname(tempLocalFile);
  const tempLocalThumbFile = path.join(os.tmpdir(), thumbFilePath);

  // Exit if this is triggered on a file that is not an image.
  if (!contentType.startsWith('image/')) {
    console.log('This is not an image.');
    deleteImage(filename);
    return null;
  }

  // Exit if the image is already a thumbnail.
  if (fileName.startsWith(THUMB_PREFIX)) {
    console.log('Already a Thumbnail.');
    deleteImage(filename);
    return null;
  }

  // Cloud Storage files.
  const bucket = gcs.bucket(object.bucket);
  const file = bucket.file(filePath);
  const thumbFile = bucket.file(thumbFilePath);
  const metadata = {
    contentType: contentType,
    // To enable Client-side caching you can set the Cache-Control headers here. Uncomment below.
    'Cache-Control': 'public,max-age=3600',
  };
  // Create the temp directory where the storage file will be downloaded.
  return mkdirp(tempLocalDir).then(() => {
    console.log('DL Started');

    // Download file from bucket.
    return file.download({
      destination: tempLocalFile
    });
  }).then(() => {
    console.log('The file has been downloaded to', tempLocalFile);
    // Generate a thumbnail using ImageMagick.
    return spawn('convert', [tempLocalFile, '-thumbnail', `${THUMB_MAX_WIDTH}x${THUMB_MAX_HEIGHT}>`, tempLocalThumbFile], {
      capture: ['stdout', 'stderr']
    });
  }).then(() => {
    console.log('Thumbnail created at', tempLocalThumbFile);
    // Uploading the Thumbnail.
    return bucket.upload(tempLocalThumbFile, {
      destination: thumbFilePath,
      metadata: metadata
    });
  }).then(() => {
    console.log('Thumbnail uploaded to Storage at', thumbFilePath);
    // Once the image has been uploaded delete the local files to free up disk space.
    fs.unlinkSync(tempLocalFile);
    fs.unlinkSync(tempLocalThumbFile);
    // Get the Signed URLs for the thumbnail and original image.
    const config = {
      action: 'read',
      expires: '03-01-2500',
    };
    return Promise.all([
      thumbFile.getSignedUrl(config),
      // file.getSignedUrl(config),
    ]);
  }).then((results) => {
    console.log('Got Signed URLs.');
    const thumbResult = results[0];
    // const originalResult = results[1];
    const thumbFileUrl = thumbResult[0];
    // const fileUrl = originalResult[0];
    // Add the URLs to the Database
    const uid = getUidFromFilePath(fileDir);
    if (!uid) return null;

    return Promise.all([
      admin.auth().updateUser(uid, {
        photoURL: thumbFileUrl
      }),
      admin.database().ref(`/users/${uid}/profile/photoURL`).set(thumbFileUrl)
    ]);
  }).then(() => console.log('Thumbnail URLs saved to database.'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 2022, the [quota limit](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#resource_limits) for the second generation of cloud functions is 32MB.