# Firebase Cloud Function Response Body Limit - Is Serverless API with Large Data Reporting Endpoints Not an Option?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, response, endpoint

My company has a larger customer using one of our *HTTP Cloud Functions* to fetch a **large body of data** in the response for his Microsoft PowerBI integration.  The trouble is, I routinely run into the *10MB response size restriction* for this guy and soon others.

Do I need to set up a dedicated API server since, with a low HTTP body length requirement documented at https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas, it seems that server-less API deployment doesn't cover my use case...?

We are heavily invested into Firebase and so far Cloud Functions have been working gloriously for every requirement we have needed to deliver on.  I'm far more into programming apps and software than I am a full devops fellow, so any direction the community could steer me in would be very valuable *because I'm not sure what new service to spin up on GCP and rebuild these endpoints into*.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to return a larger payload that Cloud Functions' maximum request size, consider writing that data to a file in Cloud Storage, and then returning the path to that file to the caller from the Cloud Function call.

Also see:

- [How to increase the max http request size limit for HTTP triggers in Cloud Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50163182/how-to-increase-the-max-http-request-size-limit-for-http-triggers-in-cloud-funct)
- [Cloud Function - Getting file contents more than 10 MB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56090400/cloud-function-getting-file-contents-more-than-10-mb)

Comment: Thank you, BTW, this is the correct advice and indeed the path we took with a solution that's working for much larger payloads.